# BS4 Scraping: Get text in span that changes location sometimes

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping data from an e-commerce website, the script was working nicely until I came across a specific error while searching for 'Air Conditioners'.

In most scenarios, I'd get the item title and the price using this code:

```
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item__info"})


    for eachContainer in containers:

        itemName = eachContainer.find("span", class_="main-title").text
        itemPrice = int(eachContainer.find("span", class_="price__fraction").text.replace('.',''))

        print(itemName + ' ' + str(itemPrice))
```

as the HTML structure is like this:

[image: regular HTML]

But the containers giving errors with my code have a different HTML structure, where the `'price_fraction'` span is inside another div

[image]

From my understanding, this happens because the `"price_fraction"` is not directly under the `"item_price"` div, but inside the `"item__price item__price-discount"` subdiv.

I added a placeholder using `try:` and hardcoding the value when an exception is raised. But I would like to still get the value, is it posible to do so?

Comment: Can you share URL of the web page?

Comment: @AndrejKesely sure, https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/electrodomesticos/climatizacion/aires-acondicionados/aire-acondicionado_Desde_97_DisplayType_G  ... The specific item giving errors is this "Aire Acondicionado Split Inverter Frio Calor Philco 5000" it seems that when they are marked as having a discount, the container changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of prices on the page, one with CSS selector `.item__price .price__fraction` and the other with `.pdp_options__text > span`.

To get all items and prices you can use this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/electrodomesticos/climatizacion/aires-acondicionados/aire-acondicionado_Desde_97_DisplayType_G'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

print('{:<10} {}'.format('Price', 'Name'))
for title, price in zip(soup.select('.main-title'),
                        soup.select('.item__price .price__fraction, .pdp_options__text > span')):

    title = title.get_text(strip=True)
    price = price.get_text(strip=True).split()[-1]

    print('{:<10} {}'.format(price, title))
```

Prints:

```
Price      Name
58.500     Aire acondicionado BGH Silent Air split frío/calor 5500 frigorías blanco 220V BSH65WCP
50.849     Aire acondicionado TCL split inverter frío/calor 2838 frigorías blanco 220V TACA-3300FCSA/INV
55.900     Aire acondicionado Philco split frío/calor 4300 frigorías negro 220V PBS50HA1AN
64.999     Aire acondicionado Philco split inverter frío/calor 4644 frigorías blanco 220V PHIN50H17N
61.899     Aire Acondicionado Split Frio Calor Midea 5461 Kcal/h 6350 W
37.999     Aire Portatil Frio/calor 3010 Fr Philco Php-32ha2an 1557 A18
30.000     Aire Split Surrey Smart 553vfh0921f Frio 2250kcal/h Tio Musa
51.499     Aire Acondicionado Split Bgh Cooltime 4500 Fc Clase A
42.219     Aire Acondicionado Noblex 5000w Nbx50h18n
40.000     Aire Acondicionado Split Frio Calor Midea Inverter 2250kcal
50.299     Aire Acondicionado Split Carrier Smart Inverter 3550 W F / C
50.499     Aire Acondicionado Noblex 5000w Nbx50h18n
39.489     Aire Acondicionado Split Surrey Pria Evolution 2300 Fr/h F/c
36.600     Aire Split Surrey Smart 553vfh0921f Frio 2250kcal 12 Cuotas
32.590     Aire Acondicionado Split Noblex Nbx32h18n 3.2kw Frio Calor
43.000     Aire Acondicionado Split Hisense Inverter Frío Calor 3200w
31.702     Aire Acondicionado Split Hitachi Frío Calor Neo Trend 2500
55.899     Aire Acondicionado Split LG Dual Inverter 3000 Frigorias Fc
36.999     Aire Acondicionado Portátil Frio Calor Sansei 3000 Frig
68.899     Aire Acondicionado Split LG Dual Inverter 3000 Frigorias F C
228.094    Aire Piso Techo Surrey Inverter 6 Tr / 18000 Frigorias F/c
27.399     Aire Acondicionado Split Philco 3350w F/c Phs32ha3an Primera
82.999     Aire Acondicionado Split Inverter Frio Calor Sanyo 5000
69.186     Aire Acondicionado Split Frio Calor Philco 5000
69.186     Aire Acondicionado Split Frio Calor Philco 5000
82.999     Aire Acondicionado Split Inverter Frio Calor Philco 5000
125.986    Aire Acondicionado Split LG Inverter Dual Cool 6000 F C
48.999     Split Philco Inverter 3300w Frio Calor Phin32h17n A18 2015
60.999     Aire Acondicionado Inverter Hyundai 5000w Frío/calor Cuotas
50.000     Aire Acond Split Hitachi Hsam5100 Eco Frío Calor 5100w
39.500     Aire Acondicionado Hyundai Split Inverter F-c 3000
29.999     Aire Acondicionado Split Hitachi 3200 Frío Calor Eco
34.159     Aire Split Tcl 2500 Frio Calor 2500fcsa Cuotas
42.999     Aire Acondicionado Inverter Samsung 3300 W 2750 Fr F/c
33.899     Aire Acondicionado Electra Split Trend A Trdo34 3400w F/c
41.499     Aire Split Frío/calor 3010 Fr Bgh Bsh35wcp 4880
43.999     Split Philco Inverter 3300w Frio / Calor Phin32h17n 2015 Pr
33.999     Aire Acondicionado Split Hitachi Frío/calor 3300fc Eco Neo
69.668     Aire Acondicionado Rca Inverter 5300w Frio Calor Rinv5300 Cu
68.249     Aire Acondicionado Hitachi Neo Trend 6300 W Frío Calor
41.999     Aire acondicionado Daewoo split inverter frío/calor 2958 frigorías blanco 220V DW6INV-3200FC
63.799     Aire acondicionado RCA split frío/calor 5418 frigorías blanco 220V LS6300FC
37.999     Aire acondicionado Surrey Winpac Eco de ventana frío 3010 frigorías blanco 220V UCVE12R8F1
31.500     Aire acondicionado BGH Cooltime split frío/calor 2650W blanco 220V CTSH23CP
48.000     Aire acondicionado Electra Geoplus SR split frío/calor 4386 frigorías blanco 220V AS52HWDJW1E
70.000     Aire acondicionado Philco split frío/calor 6350W blanco 220V PHS60H18N
75.239     Aire acondicionado Carrier XPower Inverter Smart split frío/calor 5240W blanco 220V 53HCV1801F
60.000     Aire acondicionado Surrey Vita Smart split frío/calor 6400W blanco 220V 553VFQ2201F
28.500     Aire acondicionado Sansei portátil frío/calor 3500W blanco 220V SAP32H18N
37.339     Aire acondicionado RCA split frío/calor 2236 frigorías blanco 220V RHS2600FC
35.490     Aire acondicionado Hitachi ECO split frío/calor 2750 frigorías blanco 220V HSA-3200FC ECO HI-EF
```